# PHP-FPM process timeouts but NGINX does not close the session with Client

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am using Magento with NGINX+PHP-FPM

We are facing a problem that some of our AJAX call is timing out in the PHP-FPM.
The Process in PHP-FPM gets killed but NGINX does not close the session with client.

Hence in my browser, I cannot reload the page.

Any suggestions.